# Adding 3rd shape that prompts password to unlock specific cells

Tags: vba, excel

Currently I'm using two shapes (one titled "Lock", the other "Unlock") to unlock/lock cells in a workbook. Here's the code:

Macro to lock:

```
Sub ProtectAll()
Dim wSheet As Worksheet
Dim Pwd As String
Pwd = "passwordhere"
For Each wSheet In Worksheets
    wSheet.Protect Password:=Pwd, DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True, _
        AllowFormattingColumns:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True
Next wSheet
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Master").Activate
End Sub
```

Macro to unlock:

```
Sub UnProtectAll()
Dim wSheet As Worksheet
Dim Pwd As String
Pwd = InputBox("Enter your password to unprotect all worksheets", "Password Input")
On Error Resume Next
For Each wSheet In Worksheets
    wSheet.Unprotect Password:=Pwd
Next wSheet
If Err <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "You have entered an incorrect password. All worksheets could not " & _
        "be unprotected.", vbCritical, "Incorrect Password"
End If
On Error GoTo 0
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Master").Activate
End Sub
```

My question is; How can I add a 3rd and 4th shape that prompts password to lock/unlock specific cells on several sheets? The goal is to keep everything locked except cells that have a 'price' users can change if they know the password.

The '`price`' cells I'm trying to unlock are at `J22:J163` located on `Sheet3` and `Sheet14` through `Sheet29`. Any ideas how to do this?

Another option that would work (I'd prefer answer to above but this is acceptable if anyone knows), is if the user was prompted for a password to unlock cells `J22:J163` if they tried to change any cells in `J22:J163`.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to used the locked property of cells. An example is as follows.

```
Dim Password as String
Dim UserPassword as String
Password = "Password"
UserPassword = InputBox("Enter Password")
If UserPassword = Password Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A50").Locked = False
    ActiveSheet.Protect
Else 
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A50").Locked = True
End if
```

What this code does is it sets the locked property of cells A1 to A50 to false, so that when the sheet is protected those cells can still be edited. The default state for cells is the for the locked property to be true, so every cell in you workbook should be un-editable except for the range you select. However, if the locked property happens to be set to false in some cells outside the range you want then they will be editable as well. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite an answer to the above, but I ended up using excel internal "Allow users to edit ranges" tool under the Review ribbon. Worked just fine so when users go to change certain cells it prompts for password.

Thanks!